# Как протестировать класс с закрытым конструктором и статическим полем INSTANCE?

Tags: java, тестирование, junit, рефлексия

Есть такая проблема. Есть класс-синглтон, инстанс которого получается через метод getInstance() и в дальнейшем хранится в статическом поле INSTANCE. Причём `private static Input INSTANCE = getInstance();`

Когда я пытаюсь сделать `constructor.newInstance();` он первым делом инициализирует статические поля, и выполняет getInstance(), который в случае тестирования нельзя вызывать, мне нужен только пустой инстанс. Я хочу в нём прямо просетить поля, и повызывать их сложные геттеры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Синглетон считается антипаттерном в том числе из-за никакой тестируемости.

С точки зрения тестов у *singleton* по крайней мере 2 проблемы:

- статическая инициализация, происходящая при загрузке класса (с которой вы столкнулись)
- невозможность тривиально (без ClassLoader-ной магии, например) сбросить состояние синглетона к исходному между тестами.

Чтобы как-то протестировать ваш класс и сохранить его свойства можно сделать следующее:

- Объявить публичный интерфейс для бизнес-логики.
- Логику вынести из синглтона в отдельный package-private класс, реализующий этот интерфейс. Написать для этого класса тесты в том же пакете.
- Синглтон использовать как контейнер для этого класса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Альтернатива: использовать dependency injection или ServiceLocator-ы.

Comment: Я обошёлся без такой схемы. Просто класс, где метод getInstance() и сам INSTANCE обозвал холдером, а всю начинку перенёс в package-private класс, который теперь легко инстанциируется и тестируется. А чтобы задавать поля создал package-private сеттеры. Теперь вообще нет рефлексии. Но за идею спасибо.